# Topology of Triangle Space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

The problem is to construct a topological structure on the space of all triangles in the plane, such that each triangle has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^6$.

I am confused by the space of all triangles and how to approach this problem. Is the space just all the 3-tuples such that three vertices are not co-linear?

Comment: you could allow each vertex "two degrees of freedom" moving a bit along $x$-axis, or along $y$-axis, each vertex independent of the other two.

Comment: Isn't that just another triangle? which is included by 3-tuples?

Comment: it is just another triangle, but I do not know what you mean by "included in 3-tuples". It is 3-tuples of points, each point has 2 coordinates, total 6 things (coordinates, numbers) to vary.

Comment: oh ok, I got it now, many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I think you have the right idea that a triangle in the plane is determined by three points which are not colinear. The $3$-tuple of vertices $(P_1, P_2, P_3)$ can be considered as an element of $(\mathbb{R}^2)^3\cong \mathbb{R}^6$, so consider the space 
$$ \Delta = \{ (P_1, P_2, P_3) \in \mathbb{R}^6\ |\ P_1, P_2, P_3\text{ are not colinear in }\mathbb{R}^2\} $$
with the subspace topology. Now you need to make sure that if $T\in \Delta$ is a triangle, then there is a small ball $B_\epsilon(T)\subset \mathbb{R}^6$ such that $T\in B_\epsilon(T) \subset \Delta$. If $h$ is the shortest altitude (i.e. the orthogonal distance from a vertex to the opposite edge) in $T$ then I think a ball of radius $\epsilon = \frac{h}{3}$ will suffice.

However there is some ambiguity in "what is a triangle?" Does re-ordering the vertices count as a different triangle, or should it be the same? If the order of the vertices matters then what I wrote above is an answer. However, if we want different vertex orderings to determine the same triangle then we need to think about the action of the permutation group $S_3$ on $\Delta$. In particular, given a $\sigma\in S_3$ we let it act by $\sigma\cdot(P_1, P_2, P_3)=(P_{\sigma(1)}, P_{\sigma(2)}, P_{\sigma(3)})$, and the space of *unordered* triangles can be defined by

$$\Delta' = \Delta/S_3 $$

We need to verify that this quotient space still locally looks like $\mathbb{R}^6$. Notice that this action is *free* on $\Delta$, by which I mean given any $T\in \Delta$ and $\sigma\neq 1 \in S_3$ we have $\sigma\cdot T \neq T$, because the points of $T$ cannot be equal to each other (since they are not colinear). Now the general theory of [Covering Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) kicks in and tells us that since $S_3$ is finite discrete and its action is free then the quotient map $q\colon \Delta \to \Delta'$ is a covering map, and covering maps preserve local neighbourhood structure. The details in this case would go roughly as follows: Note that since $S_3$ acts by isometries we have $\sigma\cdot B_\epsilon(T) = B_\epsilon(\sigma\cdot T)$, and by choosing $\epsilon$ small enough as above we can ensure that these $6$ different $\epsilon$ balls are all disjoint. If we let $T'=q(T)$ (i.e. it is the $S_3$ orbit of $T$) then the definition of the quotient topology tells use that $q(B_\epsilon(T))$ is an open neighbourhood of $T'$. I will leave it as an exercise to show that for each $\sigma$ the restriction $q|_{\sigma\cdot B_\epsilon(T)}$ is a homeomorphism.